# Excel formula to determine if specific text from a list is contained in a cell, then return a variable value from another list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm needing to write a formula to determine if one cell contains any specific text from another list, and then return a value based on which text is in the cell.

For example, the original cell contains things like "Do Not Buy: WMT" or "Do Not Sell: WMT, ABT, BRK.A". I need a formula to see if the ticker(s) appear in another list, which is just a column full of individual tickers. Then, depending on the match, if there is one, need it to return the value associated with the full ticker column.

[image]

As a sample, I'm needing to see if tickers from column A appear in column G, and then return the value in Column I. With the full list, there are various I values that would be returned.

`Xlookup` hasn't worked due to some containing multiple values that need to be searched for. Could delimit and split them all out but that's not the format I'm looking for. Think there might be some way to do an `if(or(isnumber(search`, but haven't figured it out.

Comment: Do you have some sample data where tickers can actually be found and matches in your lookup table? Also, what is your expected result actually looking like? It's rather unclear to me.

Comment: @JvdV - I just added a sample piece of data to the original post, hopefully that makes it more clear

Comment: You have not yet included what the results should look like. What in case of delimited values in column A, do you need delimited answers?

Comment: @JvdV The results are simply just the value in Column I, which is the "A" in the sample but other values are included in the full set. If delimited in column A, would like to have delimited in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may put you on the right track:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=MAP(TEXTAFTER(A2:A8,": "),LAMBDA(s,TEXTJOIN(", ",,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(s,", "),D2:D5,F2:F5,"<Not Found>"))))
```

Comment: This is incredible, thank you so much! Apologies about not being clear from the start but this works perfectly

Comment: If it needs to be case sensitive onbe could use `=MAP(TEXTAFTER(A2:A8,": "),LAMBDA(s,TEXTJOIN(", ",,IFERROR(INDEX(F2:F5,TOCOL(1/N(EXACT(TEXTSPLIT(s,", "),D2:D5))*SEQUENCE(ROWS(D2:D5)),2,1)),"<Not Found>"))))`